# Can I deploy to Heroku without destroying existing database? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, deployment, migration

I have made quite a large upgrade to my app. I have older version deployed on Heroku at the moment. Problem is that I have added/removed quite few migrations in the process of making my app more modular. I do not want to lose my registered user table that is already up on Heroku while deploying the update. Are there any tips someone can offer on how to preserve my user table while upgrading the app? I do have backup add-on installed but I have no clue what to do with that file.

Answer (score 0):

You should then setup your migrations more carefully since that one, which is last presented on the heroku server. So, when:

1. you are adding a column, just setup defualt value
2. you remove the column, you shell export data to (for example) YAML, and store it in the **tmp/**.
3. you are reconstructing parts of the colunms by adding and remove some of them, in migration carefully copy required data from older column (prepared to deletion) to newly created ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you're that concerned about deploying I think you might need to declare migration bankruptcy.

- Create a new migration that drops the current schema and copy the new database schema into it
- Dump out the contents of your database as CSV ( https://coderwall.com/p/jwtxjg/simple-export-to-csv-with-postgres ) or using Rails to dump in some other way (YAML etc.)
- Write a Rake task to parse the data dump into your new schema
- Set up a new database on Heroku Postgres (this does not delete the old data)
- Do a dry run locally to make sure it all works
- Promote the new database to DATABASE_URL
- Deploy, migrate, run the Rake task

Not very nice and not something you can roll back from easily if it goes wrong.